# Show bound socket (but not listen) process

Tags: linux, socket, netstat

I am trying to understand how bind() works.
I open a socket, and bind it to port 5001, but I don't execute listen() on it:

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

/* Initialize socket structure */
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
portno = 5001;

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

/* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
   perror("ERROR on binding");
   exit(1);
}

printf("bound to 5001");
getchar();
```

Then, the port is "in use":

```
$ nc -l 5001
nc: Address already in use
```

but when I try: `netstat -ntpl`, `lsof -i :5001`, `sudo netstat -antp | grep 5001` none of them shows the 5001 port.

Is there a way to see which ports are bound, and the processes that owns them?
Or, having the socket descriptor, show the port/ip/info of the socket